# In Perl, how can I change the content of an element in an XML file without changing the format of the XML?

Tags: xml, perl

I have a XML file of the format:

```
<outer1>
    <inner1>
        <name>Stonecold</name>
        <profession>warrior</profession>
        <org>wwf</org>
    </inner1>
    <inner1>
        <name>Shanebond</name>
        <profession>Bowler</profession>
        <org>newzealand</org>
    </inner1>
    <inner1>
        <name>brain schemidit</name>
        <profession>Chairman</profession>
        <org>Google</org>
    </inner1>
</outer1>
```

I want to change the value of `Shanebond` to `Shane Bond`.

I was using `XML::Simple`, but the result was a hash.

I want the same format as the input file. E.g: the output file should be as follows:

```
<outer1>
    <inner1>
        <name>Stonecold</name>
        <profession>warrior</profession>
        <org>wwf</org>
    </inner1>
    <inner1>
        <name>Shane Bond</name>
        <profession>Bowler</profession>
        <org>newzealand</org>
    </inner1>
    <inner1>
        <name>brain schemidit</name>
        <profession>Chairman</profession>
        <org>Google</org>
    </inner1>
</outer1>
```

Please advice how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

I want the output file to be saved in the same directory and if possible with the same name. is it possible?

Comment: the xml file is a config file and the component that is using it can't read the hash file. also if its format is changed after creating the file then also the component is unable to read the value from the config file

Comment: XMLin -> process contents -> XMLout

Comment: Fix the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML) has options that allow you to specify how input will be transformed into a Perl data structure and how that structure will be output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;

my $xml_file = 'b.xml';

my $xml = XMLin(
    $xml_file,
    KeepRoot => 1,
    ForceArray => 1,
);

$xml->{outer1}->[0]->{inner1}->[1]->{name} = 'Shane Bond';

XMLout(
    $xml,
    KeepRoot => 1,
    NoAttr => 1,
    OutputFile => $xml_file,
);
```

[`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML) does get a little hairy if you do anything interesting because its purpose is not to be a general purpose XML library but to provide a simple way to deal with configuration files written in XML.

CPAN has a plethora of [XML related modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XML&mode=module). Unless this was a one-off issue you had to deal with, it would be worth looking into some of the more capable and better suited modules.

Comment: I want the output file to be saved in the same directory and if possible with the same name. is it possible?

Comment: @pchakraborty Of course it is possible. Nifle even showed how to do it. The docs explain `OutputFile` clearly. Do read them occasionally: They help.

Comment: i tried this and its working properly. i have to insert it in the main code and then check the result. thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm surprised that this was accepted as "the answer", because the position of the XML element to replace is hard-coded, i.e.: if *does not* replace any occurrence of `Shanebond` with `Shane Bond`  (as I'd interpret the question), but replaces just the specific one shown in the example. If the problem were as simple as that, why bother writing a program, instead of using a text editor to replace that only occurrence?

Answer (score 8):

When it comes to reading or manipulating a XML file then [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) is often the first tool I look to use.

At first I thought it maybe an overkill for your requirement but then I noticed it did come with a parsefile_inplace() option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => { 
        name => sub { 
            $_->set_text( 'Shane Bond' )->flush  if $_->text eq 'Shanebond' 
        },
    },
)->parsefile_inplace( 'data.xml', 'bak_*' );
```

NB. If you don't want to keep a backup file then remove the second arg ('bak_*').

Comment: Note that this sort of transformation happens for every element called `name` if it has that value. It might be a `name` that belongs to a semantically different part of the config. That might be fine for your actual problem, but it is something to think about.

Answer (score 4):

Why bother processing it as XML at all?  Why not just do a regexp-replace?

```
perl -pi -e 's/Shanebond/Shane Bond/' filename.xml
```

That will do the replacement in place, keeping the same filename and everything.

Comment: This will change the first instance of that string on every line and change it. You don't want to do that. You want to find exactly the thing you mean to change and only change that. For example, suppose you wanted to change `/usr` to `/opt` for one config value. That `/usr` string is likely in other places in the config. Now you've affected all of them. Oops.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [XMLout with OutputFile](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm#OutputFile_=%3E_%3Cfile_specifier%3E_#_out_-_handy)

From the documentation for XML::Simple:

*The default behaviour of XMLout() is to return the XML as a string. If you wish to write the XML to a file, simply supply the filename using the 'OutputFile' option.

This option also accepts an IO handle object - especially useful in Perl 5.8.0 and later for output using an encoding other than UTF-8, eg:*

```
open my $fh, '>:encoding(iso-8859-1)', $path or die "open($path): $!";
XMLout($ref, OutputFile => $fh);
```

Comment: i tried this and its working properly. i have to insert it in the main code and then check the result. thanks for your help.

Comment: This answer is only "half of the solution" (at best); it seems to be a response to a comment to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327840/6607497). Don't do that!