# Adding text if missing (Perl REGEXP)

Tags: regex, perl, sed

Using a Perl replace statement (s//) I'd like to modify some XML by adding an attribute to some items if missing. Here's an example :

```
...
<car color="red" owner="john">...</car>
<car color="green" age="3">...</car>
...
```

Let's say I'd like to add a default owner to ownlerless cars. I tried the following without success :

```
s/(<car[^>]*)(?!owner="[^"]*")(.*>)|$1 owner="steve"$2/iUg
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Perl, how can I change an element in an XML file without changing the format of the XML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327720/in-perl-how-can-i-change-an-element-in-an-xml-file-without-changing-the-format)

Comment: avoid using regexes to parse / change XML or HTML documents. that's a general recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you may be able to get away with a regex, an XML parser is always recommended.

Perl/CPAN offerings include:

- [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple)

  Treats your XML document like a Perl data structure
- [`XML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser)

  An old-timer
- [`XML::SAX`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::SAX)

  For SAX parsing needs
- [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig)

  For memory-efficient processing of XML documents in chunks
- [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML)

  My personal favorite

Comment: You missed out on an opportunity to link to [the most awesome SO answer ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/301832).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2) for XML manipulation. Your problem can be solved easily in it:

```
for //car[not(@owner)] set @owner "steve" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$str = <<EOF;
<car color="red" owner="john">.*#?§<car color="pink"> </car>.*#?§</car>
<car color="green" age="3">.*#?§</car>
<car owner="bill"></car>
EOF

$str =~ s/(<car(?![^>]+?owner))([^>]*?)>/$1$2 owner="steve">/g;

print $str;
```

best regards

---

PS: most likely it's a typo but anyway, the vertical bar in your regex must be replaced by a slash

Comment: There's no need for the empty while loop.  `/g` already makes sure it runs over all elements of `$str`.  The loop just makes it run twice, and the second time around it doesn't match anything so it returns 0 (the number of matches).  This could easily become an infinite loop, for example: `s{foo}{foofoo}g`.

Comment: @Schwern thanks for your comment. I remember:`m//g != s///g` best regards